# Передача в метод имени геттера java

Tags: java, java-stream

Нужна ваша помощь.
Вычисляю максимальную длину полей экземпляров класса Racer:

```
int maxNameLength = racers.stream().map(Racer::getName).mapToInt(String::length).max().orElseThrow();
int maxTeamLength = racers.stream().map(Racer::getTeam).mapToInt(String::length).max().orElseThrow();
```

Нахождение maxNameLength практически идентично нахождению maxTeamLength, поэтому нужно сделать отдельный универсальный метод getMaxFieldLength(racers, Racer::getName/getTeam).
Не могу понять, как написать метод getMaxFieldLength, в котором передается ссылка на геттер в параметры метода.

Так не работает:

```
public static int getMaxFieldLength(List<Racer> racers, String getter) {
    return racers.stream().map(Racer::getter).mapToInt(String::length).max().orElseThrow();
    }
```

Comment: могу посоветовать вытащить названия методов рефлексией.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int getMaxFieldLength(List<Racer> racers, Function<Racer, String> getter) {
  return racers.stream().map(getter).mapToInt(String::length).max().orElseThrow();
}

int maxNameLength = getMaxFieldLength(racers, Racer::getName);
int maxTeamLength = getMaxFieldLength(racers, Racer::getTeam);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @AlexCoder Пожалуйста. Успехов.